# How do I get the registration information of a view having only the view's url?

Tags: plone

I need to get the registration information of some views (e.g. from configlets of portal_controlpanel)

Is `restrictedTraverse()` and `plone.app.customerize.registration.getViews()` the right way to get the registration information of a view programmatically?

What I've tried so far is the following:

```py
#get the url of the Mail configlet
url = [configlet['url']
        for configlet 
        in plone_site.portal_controlpanel.enumConfiglets('Plone') 
        if configlet['title'] == 'Mail'
        ][0]

url = extract_url(configlet['url'])
#url is now '/Plone/@@mail-controlpanel'
view = plone_site.restrictedTraverse(url)
view.__name__
reg = [reg
        for reg
        in plone.app.customerize.registration.getViews(zope.interface.Interface)
        if reg.name == view.__name__
        ][0]
reg.factory
reg.factory.__base__
reg.factory.template
reg.factory.template.filename
reg.info
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you meant by "registration information". You are talking of how the view is registered in ZCML?

Comment: Yes. I want to get the information which was registered via the zcml. But I don't want to get the string from the zcml-file but the part in Plone/Zope in which this is stored (I guess the globalSiteManager).